# Android (12) Java - Intent ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT - EXTRA_INITIAL_URI don't work

Tags: java, android

I want the user of my app to select a PDF file, then my app open the file.
My app use Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT
The initial directory is set with  intent.putExtra(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI,uri);
as describe in official doc : https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files#grant-access-directory
Here is the code.

```
    ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> GetDoc2 = registerForActivityResult(
            new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
            new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {

                @Override
                public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
                    Log.d("Thierry", "Dans On Activity ResultS 222, result = "+result);
                    // Add same code that you want to add in onActivityResult method
                }
            });

    private void openFile() {
        Context context = getActivity().getBaseContext();
        String DIR="/sdcard/eduphone";
        String PDF= "/sdcard/eduphone/EDphone.pdf";
        String FILE=PDF;
        Log.d("Thierry", "FILE="+FILE);
        File file = new File(FILE);
        Uri uri;
        if (file.exists()) {
            Log.d("Thierry", "Build.VERSION.SDK_INT"+ Build.VERSION.SDK_INT);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                Log.d("Thierry", "Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES");
                uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID+".provider", file);
            } else {
                uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
                Log.d("Thierry", "Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES");
            }
            Log.d("Thierry", "File existe");
            Log.d("Thierry", "INST APP U URI= "+uri);
            Log.d("Thierry", "INST APP U PATH = "+uri. getPath());


            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
            intent.putExtra(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI,uri);
            intent.setType("application/pdf");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            GetDoc2.launch(intent);
            //result.launch("application/pdf");
               }else{
            Log.d("Thierry", "File Not exist");
        }
    }
```

But it does not work, the initial directory is always the last emplacement.
Any idea ?
Thanks a lot

Comment: You use both ACTION_,OPEN_DOCUMENT and ACTION_GET_CONTENT. Dont do such nasty things

Comment: can you show all the project please

Comment: I have put all sources on this drive : https://drive.edcloud.fr/s/mpzqyxs3Pk4BHar

Answer (score 0):

Quoting [the documentation for `EXTRA_INITIAL_URI`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/DocumentsContract#EXTRA_INITIAL_URI):

> Location should specify a document URI or a tree URI with document ID. If this URI identifies a non-directory, document navigator will attempt to use the parent of the document as the initial location.

In other words, the `Uri` needs to be a `Uri` that you obtained previously from the Storage Access Framework, such as from a previous `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` call. You are not using such a `Uri`, and so what you are using will not work.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I changed the code. Now, in my fragment, uri is static, I initialize it in onCreateView, the result is the same, initial directory is always Download.

Comment: Well show your new code. We all wonder what you had to initialize. Show that you use an earlier obtained uri. Away with that FileProvider too of course.

Comment: @Coilhac: "Now, in my fragment, uri is static" -- that seems unlikely to work.

Comment: I do not understand "Earlier", ... before what ? I initialize it as soon as the fragment is created. I put in " static Uri Inst_uri;" the result of "uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", file);"  Have you a link to a page which explain how to get uri for a file or a dir in external storage ( ex / sdcard/toto) ?

Comment: @Coilhac: What you want is not an option, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

As says @Commonsware, what I want to to is not possible.
I wanted my app to let the user select a PDF file thanks to Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT. At this step,  it's fine.
But : I want to set the initial directory from where he navigates, using EXTRA_INITIAL_URI, defining **myself** this initial directory.
I understand that it is not possible. Initial directory is defined with a Uri, this Uri can only be return with such Storage Access Framework (SAF)  mechanism.
If we define this Uri with another way (Uri.fromFile(file), FileProvider.getUriForFile), it does not work.
( do not hesitate to react if I misunderstand).
Thierry

Answer (score -1):

try this code

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.setType("application/pdf");
        intent.putExtra(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI,uri);
        startActivity(intent)
        GetDoc2.launch(intent);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. With this code it always start in Downloads.

Comment: if you have some Error , Share it please

Comment: Here are level:error in logcat :
2024-02-07 21:23:13.800 30896-30896 oid.documentsu          com.google.android.documentsui       E  No package ID ff found for ID 0xffffffff.
2024-02-07 21:23:13.809   931-3051  BufferQueueDebug        surfaceflinger                       E  [com.google.android.documentsui/com.android.documentsui.picker.PickActivity$_30896#0](this:0xb400007cbfee4948,id:-1,api:0,p:-1,c:-1) id info cannot be read from 'com.google.android.documentsui/com.android.documentsui.picker.PickActivity$_30896#0'

Comment: You also use both ACTION_,OPEN_DOCUMENT and ACTION_GET_CONTENT. Dont do such nasty things. Further you are not showing the value of used uri.

Comment: Same result if I remove ACTION_GET_CONTENT
URI= content://eu.eduphone.install.provider/external/Download/eduphone
PATH of URI = /external/Download/eduphone

Comment: Did you get that uri using ACTION_GET_CONTENT before? Strange provider/aithority. Where did you get it from? As it is not a normal uri for a file on external storage.

Comment: @blackapp : the URI if provided by :  " uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", file);"  In my file-path.xml I have :     <external-path         name="external"         path="." />

Comment: My god ..  read... use only an uri earlier obtained by action get content.... read .. dont use file provider... sigh...