# Android Java - set EXTRA_INITIAL_URI in ActivityResultLauncher<String> .... new ActivityResultCallback<Uri>()

Tags: java, android, getcontent

I want to let the user of my app choose a file, then the app open this file. For opening the file, I need its uri.
In the official documentation https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result#launch I see this simple example :

```
ActivityResultLauncher<String> mGetContent = registerForActivityResult(new GetContent(),
    new ActivityResultCallback<Uri>() {
        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(Uri uri) {
            // Handle the returned Uri
        }
});
```

Called with :
        `mGetContent.launch("image/*");`

That allows to open the selected file. Exactly what I need.

But I'd like to define an initial directory, called EXTRA_INITIAL_URI, but this can be set with a putExtra like this :
`intent.putExtra(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI,uri);`

The problem is that there is no intent in this kind of implementation.
So my question is : is it possible to define a EXTRA_INITIAL_URI , if yes how ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can use from ActivityResultContracts StartActivityForResult. Then you can use an intent for ACTION_GET_CONTENT and put extras on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GetContent`, and the `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` that it is named after doesn't support `EXTRA_INITIAL_URI` at all: the [list of intents it does support](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/DocumentsContract#EXTRA_INITIAL_URI) include:

> - `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`
> - `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT`
> - `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`

which is why it isn't a parameter on that particular Activity Result Contract.

You'll note that [`OpenDocumentTree`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/result/contract/ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocumentTree) specifically states:

> The input is an optional Uri of the initial starting location.

Which maps to setting the `EXTRA_INITIAL_URI` for that Activity Result contract, so you can use that contract directly if you are trying to select a folder.

For the other two, [`CreateDocument`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/result/contract/ActivityResultContracts.CreateDocument) and [`OpenDocument`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/result/contract/ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocument), both specifically state:

> This can be extended to override [`createIntent`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/result/contract/ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocument#createIntent(android.content.Context,kotlin.Array)) if you wish to pass additional extras to the Intent created by `super.createIntent()`.

Which means you'd extend that contract to set the initial Uri.

For example, if you wanted to pass in the initial Uri as a constructor parameter to the contract, you'd write the class as

```
public class OpenDocumentAtFolder extends ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocument {
    private final Uri initialUri;

    public CustomContract(@NonNull Uri initialUri) {
        this.initialUri = initialUri;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Intent createIntent(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull String[] input) {
        return super.createIntent(context, input)
                .putExtra(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI, initialUri);
    }
}
```

Which you'd then use in place of `GetContent`:

```
ActivityResultLauncher<String> mOpenDocumentAtFolder = registerForActivityResult(
    new OpenDocumentAtFolder(yourDefaultUriHere),
    new ActivityResultCallback<Uri>() {
        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(Uri uri) {
            // Handle the returned Uri
        }
});
```

The [guide to creating custom contracts](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result#custom) talks more about writing type safe contracts if, for example, you wanted to instead have to pass the Uri and a mime type to `launch`, you could write your own custom contract that doesn't extend `OpenDocument` at all, but instead just uses the same underlying Intent extras that you want.

Comment: Also, since the asker [asked this question a few hours earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77956532/115145), note that the `Uri` supplied to `EXTRA_INITIAL_URI` needs to be a document or tree `Uri`, obtained from some prior interaction with the Storage Access Framework (e.g., `ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocument`).

Comment: Thanks a lot @ianhanniballake,  very clear ! I have implemented your recommendation. It does not work, but as CommonWare says, I think I have a problem with my uri. When this problem will be solve, I will adopt your solution.